# IS there any way to place the symbol in its original coordinates in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, artboard, symbols

Is there any way to place the symbol in its original coordinates? lets say I drew a path that have a coordinates of 3cm from the **top right** position of my artboard. and I make it as a symbol. now in a new artboard that have different dimension, I need to place the symbol I did, in the same position that it was in my first artboard, and have the same coordinates related to the new artboard dimension.

as you may know using the [place symbol instance] tool is placing the symbol in the center of your view port regardless its dimension. my question is how to change the position of the symbol using that tool.?

Comment: paste in place :))

Comment: sorry, I don't mean to copy and past, I mean in a new document using my library of symbols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the transform panel to move objects to a specific location. 
Also note that in the panel options you can change whether or not to use the Symbol's registration point. If you choose not to use the symbol's reference point, you can use the transform panel's reference point tool (the square to the left of the inputs - selecting one of the filled in squares sets the reference point). Then input the x/y coordinates and the size of the symbol as needed.

But as for automatically placing the symbol in a specific location - there's no way to do this that I'm aware of... well... maybe with a script? But even that approach is still not 100% automatic as you have to trigger the script.